# When returning to a state, when does $scope reload?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, ionic-framework

I have a `list` object in the parent state of this controller. Every time I load the state that uses this controller, `$scope.items` is emptied and the controller must load the data from the parent scope again.

`ListCtrl` corresponds to the `list` state. The parent state contains many lists.

```
.controller('ListCtrl', ['$scope','$state','$timeout',
    function($scope, $state, $timeout) {
    console.log($scope.items); // undefined
    if(!$scope.items) { // always evaluates to true
        $timeout(function() {
            $scope.items = $scope.$parent.list.items;
        }, 500);
    } else { 
        console.log($scope.items); // never executes here
    }
}])
```

It was my understanding that AngularJS by default caches some views. Does this mean the caching does not apply to the scope variables in the cached views? And most importantly, is there a way to cache this `$scope.items` so that every time I return to this state, there isn't this timeout delay?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution ended up being to check if the $rootScope.list.item had been loaded, instead of just the $scope.item.

```
if(!$rootScope.list) {
    $timeout(function() { 
        $scope.items = $rootScope.list.items; 
    }, 1000);
} else { 
    $scope.items = $rootScope.list.items; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As a beginner of AngularJS, what I understand is that $scope.items is only defined within the current controller. If you want to load items in your html content, just define items under that controller used in that specified html tag.

I made up a [toy example](http://jsfiddle.net/35dqLq7L/) ,

```
angular.module('scopeExample', [])
.controller('MyController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.username = 'World';

}]);
```

which is similar to that on [AngularJS Scope documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope).

Comment: $scope local to the controller and view. But scopes are linked together via the state machine in the `.config()` block of your app. That's why you can call `$scope.$parent` and retrieve the parent scope's data. 

However, this data is loaded asynchronously, so the parent scope is usually not loaded before the current one.

Answer (score 0):

**Parent Controller**

```
 .controller('parentController', ['$scope','$state','$timeout','$rootScope'
        function($scope, $state, $timeout, $rootScope) {
        $rootScope.items=['item 1','item 2'];
    }])
```

**Another Controller**

```
.controller('ListCtrl', ['$scope','$state','$timeout','$rootScope'
        function($scope, $state, $timeout,$rootScope) {
        console.log($rootScope.items); // Should give the result
        if(!$scope.items) { // always evaluates to true
            $timeout(function() {
                $scope.items = $scope.$parent.list.items;
            }, 500);
        } else { 
            console.log($scope.items); // never executes here
        }
    }])
```

Dont forget to add $rootScope on top.

Comment: The problem with this solution is the time delay. `$rootScope` loads after the controller executes the `console.log()`. My first solution was to use $timeout. But I only want to use it once. I have 3 list states, each of which contains a different list.

Also tried using `$broadcast`. But the events are not being received by the child states, presumably because they haven't been loaded yet.

Comment: I am not sure on this "$rootScope loads after the controller executes the console.log()". Did you change everything to $rootScope.

Comment: I figured out the answer. The conditional case I should have used was to test whether the `$rootScope` variable I was looking for existed. If it didn't use a timeout delay before assignment. Otherwise immediately make the assignment.

Presumably, this means that `$scope` must initialized every time the view is loaded.